# Print the value of a Java constructor

Tags: java

I am a java beginner and I am trying to get used to objects. Is there anyway that I can print out the value of a constructor in main? How can I print out the value's Kevin,20? Thanks

```
public class MainConstructor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConstructorClass emp1 = new ConstructorClass("Kevin", 20);
    }
}
```

//Constructor Class

```
public class ConstructorClass {

    private String name;
    private int number;

    public ConstructorClass(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        System.out.println("called");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(name + "," + number);`

Comment: You could also implement getter/setter moethods...

Comment: You can implement the following method in your class:
 
public void print (){
System.out.println(name + "," + number)
}

and than call emp1.print();

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using toString() in your class

```
public String toString() {
        return this.name + "," + this.number;
    }
```

and in your main just do `emp1.toString();` to print it to your console

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there any difference between `emp1.toString()` and `emp1` ?

Comment: I think you can do emp1.toString(); or System.out.println(emp1); ( to print in the console) It'd be the same. since the toString is the default print value of a class you're only overriding it, so you change the output of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `toString()` method to `ConstructorClass`:

```
public String toString() {
    return name + "," + number;
}
```

Then call this from `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConstructorClass emp1 = new ConstructorClass("Kevin",20);
    System.out.println(emp1.toString());
}
```

Comment: `emp1.toString()` is equivalent to `emp1` I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor is basically just another method (but for the love of what is holy, never say that during interview or even to your professor) so there is nothing wrong with doing this:

```
public class ConstructorClass {
private String name;
private int number;
public ConstructorClass(String name, int number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    System.out.println(name+" "+number);
    }
}
```

But this solution is really ugly and kind of "hotfixy". Better solution would be to have constructor to only get the values and have separate method to print what you want:

```
public ConstructorClass(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
}
void printNameAndNumber() {
        System.out.println(name+" "+number);
}
```

And use the class like this in your main

```
ConstructorClass c = new ConstructorClass("John",85)
c.printNameAndNumber();
```

Also some people like to handle this by going through hoops and loops and overriding `ToString`, but that is being too overzealous and there is really no benefit in your case (or any other primitive case).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ConstructorClass(String name, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        System.out.println(name + "," + number);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to properly print out those values, you should have getter methods set in your methods

Example below

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}
```

Then to print those values, you should then use methods toString() and method print() to display your values

Example

```
public String toString(){
   return getName() + " " + getNumber();
}

public void print(){
   System.out.println(toString());
}
```

Then in the class with the main method, you call your print method for that specific class

Example

```
ConstructorClass emp1 = new ConstructorClass("Kevin",20);
emp1.print();
```

Hope this helped, Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.